# Stored procedure doesn't have the same result when calling from PL/SQL developer and SQL*plus

Tags: bash, oracle, stored-procedures, sqlplus

I'm trying to call a procedure from a shell script using sql*plus but I'm running into a weird issue.

My procedure starts by loading data into a cursor from a table.
Then, for each line of the cursor, it's calling another procedure that's supposed to insert data into another table. After that, it updates the lines read from the first table to include a "work done" timestamp.

When I call this procedure from PL/SQL Developer, everything works fine, and I get my data into the second table.
When I call the same procedure from sql*plus, it tells me everything works fine (returns 0), the "work done" timestamp is added, but I get no data inserted into the second table.

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing that.

here's the line used in the script to call the procedure:

```
echo exit | sqlplus -S $schema @call_to_procedure.sql
```

$schema is schema/pwd@db

call_to_procedure.sql is

```
set serveroutput on feedback off
declare
  V_RETURN number(1);
begin
  SCHEMA.PACKAGE.PROCEDURE(V_RETURN);
  dbms_output.put_line(V_RETURN);
end;
/
```

And here is the procedure code (I hope I didn't remove too much, but basically what is gone is the cursor's select query's filters)

```
PROCEDURE MYPROC (v_result out NUMBER) IS
    v_id_smth number(10);
    v_id_smthelse number(10);
    v_data varchar2(10);
    v_errmsg CLOB;

    CURSOR data_to_load IS
        SELECT t1.id_smth as id_smth, t1.data as data, t2.smthelse as smthelse
        FROM t1, t2
        WHERE t1.id_smth = t2.id_smth
        AND other controls
    ;

BEGIN
    FOR data in data_to_load
    LOOP
        v_id_smth := data.id_smth;
        v_id_smthelse := data.id_smthelse;
        v_data := data.data; -- sorry about that renaming scheme :/

        BEGIN
            INSERT_DATA_INTO_OTHER_TABLE(v_id_smth, v_id_smthelse, v_data);
        END;
    END LOOP;

    UPDATE T1
    SET date_processing = SYSDATE
    WHERE date_processing IS NULL;

    v_result = 0;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHER THEN
    v_errmsg := SQLCODE || '-' || SQLERRM || '; v_id_smth : ' || v_id_smth || '; v_id_smthelse : ' || v_id_smthelse;
    LOG_PACKAGE.LOG_PROC('MY_PROC', v_errmsg);
    v_result := 1;

END MYPROC;
```

*edit for clarification:*
Both procedures are in the same schema/package, and I'm logged in as schema owner in both instances (PL Developper & sql*plus).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the problem is in the environment variables and national calendar settings.
Here is a simple example when the day of the week is 4 or 5, depending on the national calendar.
For example,  bat file

```
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_RUSSIA.CL8MSWIN1251
(
echo  connect  / as sysdba
echo  @E:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql
echo exit
)| sqlplus   /nolog
```

E:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql

```
select to_char(sysdate,'D') from dual;
```

Output

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Feb 6 22:53:20 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> Connected.


SQL>
T
-
4
```

change to  AMERICA in NLS_LANG

```
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251
(
echo  connect  / as sysdba
echo  @E:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql
echo exit
)| sqlplus   /nolog
```

E:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql

```
 select to_char(sysdate,'D') from dual;
```

Output:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Feb 6 22:56:42 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> Connected.

SQL>
T
-
5
```

Comment: Well the only thing I get when executing my procedure from the shell is a date, which is correct, so I don't think this is it. The issue seems to be more than it flies over the loading of the cursor, leaving it empty so my loop on the cursor's data doesn't do anything. The second query in my procedure is just a massive update of all the lines that have no data in a specific date field to add those dates, which is correctly executed.

Comment: Remove all implicit type conversions in the where clause ` WHERE t1.id_smth = t2.id_smth AND other controls` and make explicit type conversions.

Comment: Add ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=',.' or '.,'

Answer (score 1):

Another option, is who you log in as the same on SQL*Plus as SQL*Developer? If a procedure is created with INVOKER RIGHTS, different user accounts executing it may have different results depending on their permissions - which may not be obvious, especially if the procedure suppresses exceptions.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should've said that in the OP, but I'm logging in as the same user (owner of the schema/package), so that's not it unfortunately. Both procedures (the one called in the shell script and the one called by the first procedure are in the same schema, with the same rights, and are set to log exceptions in a separate table, which remains rather empty.